# Designing a global event handler

Tags: events, design-patterns, event-handling

We're currently looking at setting up standards for events that are shared across the system. We work with data that changes often and having a way for all our independent systems to communicate and perform event driven tasks we believe a global event system will be the key to success.

Our product has a large amount (Actually, probably not that large, but I can imagine we're looking at about 1-2 million updates a day) of everchanging data and we need to keep up with these changes. We are able to track changes on the front end, through state management, but on the back end, due to having a large amount of microservices, it is a much bigger task.

A common change, for example, is when a user decides to pay for an order. We have a microservice that handles that order processing, but our analytics service wants to pick up on that processing to track it as a paid order and contribute it towards the daily earnings.

My belief is that we should have a standardised approach using topics for each domain object (eg. Orders/Customers/Payments) in a global event bus with a standardised object with fields like:

- Object Id
- Version (To track protocol changes, etc)
- The object itself (Potentially through graphql instead of the entire object, though there are some pitfalls to this)

I'd then look to push all this information in to something like Amazon SNS where each sub-system could digest the notifications however they like.

My question is really looking for advice on how to approach this and for some anecdotes from people that have attempted this before (Even if you've done something different that would be awesome to hear) to not make too many mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize requirements -

- 1-5 million events per day
- 1:N pattern. One or more data/events producers with multiple consumers that need to be notified
- Standardised object structure
- Multiple microservices
- Amazon SNS

A message broker would be the perfect solution. I wrote a [blog post](https://memphis.dev/blog/here-is-why-you-need-a-message-broker/) explaining why.

Basically, the event handlers will act as producers and consumers.
The first handler that will handle payment will produce an event to the broker to a certain topic (or station in [Memphis{dev}](https://memphis.dev) semantics) where the rest of the handlers will listen for new events, consume them and continue processing. It will also allow you to add many more handlers as needed or as the business requires without damaging the others.
Last but not least, scale and workload sizes. Traditional protocols and direct communication between microservices cannot absorb such workloads, a dedicated store can.

Based on the requirements, [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) would be a great fit because of the extra features it embeds, like a schema registry for schema standardization and connectors where you can connect SNS, for example.
Apache pulsar can also work great.

If you prefer a cloud-native, modern, small footprint, easy-to-onboard solution, I recommend you to get with [Memphis](https://memphis.dev)